# Upright parentheses in italic text in ConTeXt

Tags: fonts, context

Is there a nice way to automatically turn all parentheses in italic text upright in ConTeXt? In particular i'm interested in a solution which would work with EB Garamond. My current workaround is to define a fallback in my typescript file, which forces upright parentheses into italics, like so:

```
\definefontfeature
    [eb-garamond-test]
    [default]
    [itlc=yes]
    \definefontfallback [uprightparenteses] [name:EBGaramond-Regular] [0x00028:0x00029] [force=yes] 
    \starttypescript [serif] [ebgaramond-test]
        \setups[font:fallback:serif]
        \definefontsynonym [Serif] [name:EBGaramond-Regular] [features=eb-garamond-test]
        \definefontsynonym [SerifItalic] [name:EBGaramond-Italic] [features=eb-garamond-test,fallbacks=uprightparenteses]
    \stoptypescript
    \starttypescript [ebgaramond-test]
        \definetypeface[ebgaramond-test] [rm] [serif] [ebgaramond-test] [default]
    \stoptypescript

\setupbodyfont[ebgaramond-test]

\starttext
({\em if (if) if})
\stoptext
```

The only problem for now is that italics correction `itlc=yes` obviously doesn't affect these and it doesn't look good (the ones outside are genuine roman ones, with working italics correction, and the ones inside are fake with no italics correction):

[image: upright parentheses]

**UPD:**

Ok, one possible solution is to do what i did (use a font fallback for parentheses) and, add as @dg suggests below, add `\setupitaliccorrection[global,always]` to make italics correction work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set italic correction to `always`:

```
\setupitaliccorrection
  [global,always]
```

[image]

Comment: Magic! But how does it know that fallback italics are italics?

Comment: @SergeySlyusarev Some details are given in [Fonts out of ConTeXt](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/fonts-mkiv.pdf)